# How to select restrictive data on sql using like

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE tagName LIKE '%ABC%' OR tagName LIKE '%DEF%';
```

I want to limit the number of data I get from each like.
Is possible?

Comment: Use 2 selects with a union and change the selects to have only 1 like and a limit clause?

Comment: Yes. you're right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `UNION ALL`, but you have to nest each one of the statements as a subquery so that `LIMIT` can work, otherwise it's syntactically wrong:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE tagName LIKE '%ABC%' LIMIT 10) t
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE tagName LIKE '%DEF%' LIMIT 10) t
```

Note: LIMIT without ORDER BY is never a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

You could separate the queries by `LIKE` and specify the `limit`, finally `UNION ALL`

```
(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE tagName LIKE '%ABC%' LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE tagName LIKE '%DEF%' LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: So nice! Thank you very much

Comment: @h2jun . . . This is the better syntax.  An additional layer of subqueries is not needed for this.